# Unsure how to retrieve data from a custom endpoint?

Tags: heroku, ember.js, ember-data

Context to this post is I'm a java developer attempting to teach myself Ember. It isn't going well. I realize this question is pretty vague so I apologize, I'm not even sure what I should be asking...

I need to pull data into a model, i.e. via some sort of query, from a heroku json endpoint. In the application.js file, I have the following:

```
import DS from ‘ember-data’;

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    host: 'https://cag-brain.herokuapp.com'
});
```

Ideally I would like to pull this data into a user model, then display that data on a page as a sort of proof of concept. This unfortunately gets me nothing. Nor am I even sure I'm going about this correctly. Should I be doing something different than attempting to use Host Customization? Any guidance would be **much** appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different things involved for retrieving records via ember-data.

First of all you should [define your models](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/models/defining-models/):

```
// app/models/post.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string')
});
```

You should retrieve records in a [`model` hook of a `route`](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/).

```
// app\routes\posts.js

import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('post');
  }
});
```

Then you should configure your [api host](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/models/customizing-adapters/#toc_host-customization) and maybe a [namespace](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/models/customizing-adapters/#toc_endpoint-path-customization). You included that step in your question:

```
// app/adapters/application.js

import DS from ‘ember-data’;

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    host: 'https://cag-brain.herokuapp.com'
});
```

If your api does not implement [JSON Api specification](http://jsonapi.org/) you need to customize your [serializer](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/models/customizing-serializers/) and [adapter](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/models/customizing-adapters/). Ember-data ships with a [RESTAdapter](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.16/classes/DS.RESTAdapter)/[RestSerializer](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.16/classes/DS.RESTSerializer) additionally to the default adapter and serializer which implements JSON Api spec. There is also one abstract [adapter](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.16/classes/DS.Adapter) and [serializer](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.16/classes/DS.Serializer) If you need to start from scratch. Before that I would definitely have a look if there is any [community adapter/serializer](https://emberobserver.com/categories/ember-data-adapters) fitting your needs.

To decouple api and client development and to speed up tests I would recommend [ember-cli-mirage](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/) which allows you to mock your api.